# where does neo4j browser store the colors assigned to the Entities

Tags: neo4j

So I have deployed a neo4j server on a server and loaded some test data. When I use the neo4j-browser to look at one Entity type, a nice blue circle appears.

When I use a different computer with a separate web-browser the very same Entity appears in pink.

Now, I am led therefore to believe that the Entity colours are stored as cookies on the web-browser. However, using an 'incognito' web-browser still gives the nice pink circle.

What gives here? Where are the colours (and sizes etc) which can be set in the neo4j-browser stored?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser saves automatically GRASS stylesheets when you apply custom colors.

A guide is available on the Neo4j developers documentation :
http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/

You can also reset the styling by typing `:style reset` in the browser console bar.